# Why can my body conduct electricity from a 9 volt battery?

Tags: voltage, amperage, electricity, conductivity

I've created a scenario represented identically in the attached image [image: Circuit]. My question is this:

When I connect Jumper 1 to my left hand and Jumper 2 to my right, the LED turns on very faintly but I feel no shock. I have done much research that all seems to contradict itself and I simply cannot understand: How is the electricity travelling through my body, and at what voltage and amperage?

Comment: You are a bag of salty water with sweaty fingers.

Comment: So the electricity is travelling across my skin and not through my bloodstream?

Comment: Probably not at least at the frequencies you are working with, your skin has a much higher resistance than your salty wet innards.  Anything that pierces it, even a low electrical potential gradient in a water bath if you have a minor cut, can make this very apparent.

Comment: So if it is travelling through my body, why isn't the amperage killing me?

Comment: In a very dark room, waiting for awhile until your eyes are dark-adjusted, you might be able to see dim light emanating from the LED with 50 microamps flowing. You likely wouldn't feel that current. Very roughly 3.5V of the 5V would be dropped across your body.

Comment: Touch the 2 jumpers to your tongue. Beware: this may hurt a bit.

Comment: @analogsystemssrf I believe the tongue test for a 9v battery is now recommended against(although if there have been injuries the incidence rate is admittedly low.  A wet finger will suffice.  There are many different ways electricity can injure or kill you, with conduction the primary danger is fibrillation, which is basically disruption of the control circuit for your heart.  50-100mA AC is considered ideal for stopping the human heart, whereas higher currents may cause internal burns and external currents can cause flash/burn damage.  At low currents, DC is less dangerous than AC.

Comment: At even lower currents, neither is particularly dangerous, although parts of your body (heart, brain) are more susceptible to small currents.  The current you can safely carry from the thumb to pinky finger of the same hand is much greater than that which you can safely carry over your heart.  At sufficiently high currents you could even be more or less vaporized, in which case the danger to your heart is irrelevant and the danger to non-current carrying bystanders becomes great.  At whatever voltage/current you are working with, different aspects of safety must be considered.

Comment: Working with a very large 6V battery for example, you could consider the terminals of the battery touch-safe.  You can complete the circuit with yourself with very little danger of the resulting microcurrent hurting you.  You must still not let down your guard in other ways because, for example, if you were to short the terminals with a large wrench or hand tool, you could still create a flash sufficient to damage your eyes.  Connecting a component wrong could cause unplanned rapid dissassembly with some danger of shrapnel, flash and dangerous vapors.

Comment: By the way, connecting 9v to Arduino does not matter, the output is 5V as seen in the picture.

Comment: A friend did a test in his cabin with thoroughly dark-adjusted eyes and a very good green LED. Threshold of visiblity was reportedly around 1nA, 1/50,000 of what Glen suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Current depends on voltage and resistance.  Look up ["Ohm's law"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)

E=IR

Where E is voltage in volts, I is current in amperes, and R is resistance in ohms.

Using 5V and assuming a reasonable  value for skin resistance of [10000 ohms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_injury)  you get 0.5 milliamperes of current.

An efficient LED can produce visible light levels with that amount of current.

Your skin resistance varies depending on many factors.  It is lower when you sweat and higher when your skin is dry.

This makes it difficult to guess how much current is really flowing, but obviously some current is getting through.

---

It isn't hurting you because the current is very low.  It takes a **lot** more current, and it has to pass through your heart, to kill you.

I have been plugged into 110VAC, and I am still here.  I do not recommend you try it.  It hurts like hell, and can kill you.  I got lucky.  My brother (who accidentally zapped me) noticed quickly enough and unplugged the cable I had been working on.  It is certain that I could not have let go on my own, and would have eventually died if it had gone on longer.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot more sense, I'll do some more research

Comment: My teacher in Electricity 9 warned us about any current going through the heart. His tip was to always keep one hand in your pocket. Needless to say, that became the running joke for the rest of the year. "Wait, you forgot to put your hand in your pocket! "

Comment: [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5R-KBa18ME&t=4s) is a video of someone testing the affects of different levels of current passing through his body.

Comment: "It takes a lot more current, and it has to pass through your heart, to kill you." Actually, back in the early days of pacemakers there was an incident involving a line-powered pacemaker and an improperly-grounded hospital bed frame. The lethal current turned out to be 47 uA.

Comment: Usually, voltage is referred to as 'U' while 'E' is for Energy.

Comment: @Damien:  Depends on where you learned it.  The school I went to and the books we used, it was "E" for "electromotive force."

Comment: quote 'Electromotive force is the electric potential generated by either a electrochemical cell or a changing magnetic field.'